# Confusing Result with @Session["something_here"] (C#/Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, razor, webmatrix

I am testing a few things here in a basic webpage, and I noticed something very odd. I'm not sure if this behavior is to be expected, but it does make me wonder...

I know I can get the Current User ID of the person currently logged in, like so:

```
@WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
```

And just to see how Sessions are used, I thought I'd just store (as an example) the CurrentUserId in a Session variable once the user logs in, like this:

```
@Session["UserIDthing"] = @WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
```

And then on another page, I just output the session id (which should be exactly equal to 1, because thats what my UserId is), like this:

```
@Session["UserIDthing"]
```

But, instead of it outputting "1", it outputs minus 1 "-1". Why does this happen?

[image]

And just to make sure I was right about the user id, I outputted the user id using:

```
@WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
```

And it displayed the correct ID, which is just "1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably has nothing to do with `Session`.  Try to store the `@WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` some other way to ensure that the `CurrentUserId` has actually been set after the user logs in (maybe by logging it to a file or use a static variable for testing).

Comment: Thank you! Instead of storing it in Session right after they've logged in, I store it in Session when they have been redirected to the Account page after they've been logged in. So you're right, it wasn't being set at that time. Thanks :) @Eben R.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a variable, you need a code block, not an output block. You should use:

```
@{ someVar = otherVar; }
```

The syntax you use:

```
@someVar = @otherVar;
```

is translated as (pseudo code):

```
Response.Write(HtmlEncode(someVar));
Response.Write(" = ");
Response.Write(HtmlEncode(otherVar));
Response.Write(";");
```

<strike>BTW: Why do you assign session variables in your view. This should be the responsability of the controller.</strike>

Comment: No such thing as Views and Controllers in Web Pages.

Comment: @Mike, I see, its WebMatrix. I try to forget architectures like that.

Comment: Ignorance will get you nowhere.